# What is 'definite' variable in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, terminology, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, observables

I have gone through a few of the questions on the website regarding this particular query, but I have not understood what they meant.

When a question says that a particle has definite momentum, are they saying it neglecting the approximations implied by uncertainty principle?

Because in QM, as far as I know, there can not be anything known beyond a certain limit.

**P.S.** I have a high school math background.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not precise enough about what the problem here is: Is it: a) that you think that no state in QM can ever have zero uncertainty for *any* observable, b) that you think no state can ever have zero uncertainty for *momentum* because that would violate the uncertainty principle?

Comment: Are you sure the term you've seen is "definite" and not "well-defined"? The latter is part of the standard terminology but the former isn't (much). If it's the former, you should provide explicit links to where you've seen it being used.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: (a), and so (b)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I've seen "definite". I heard my professor use it explaining the square well problem - a particle with definite momentum. But I guess now that he really meant 'almost' definite momentum, with the uncertainties included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have understood your question as two separate questions.

> 1. What does it mean that a state has *definite* momentum?

A general state $|\psi \rangle$in quantum mechanics is a superposition of different eigenstates $|p\rangle$ of the momentum operator:

$$|\psi \rangle=\int \psi(p)|p \rangle dp$$

I have written this for 1 dimension, since the concept does not change in 3d.

However, you can consider the case that $|\psi \rangle=|p \rangle$. Actually there are some issues with this, as $|p\rangle$ is not normalizable, but it works to some approximation. The state $|p \rangle $ is a state with *definite momentum* in the sense that it has a 100% probability to give momentum $p$, and 0% probability to give any other momentum.

> 2. Doesn't such a state violate the uncertainty principle?

Good question, and I see why you'd think so,  but it does not! We wish for

$$\sigma_x \sigma_p \geq \hbar/2$$

Where $\sigma_x , \sigma_p$ are the standard deviations in the x and p probability distributions, respectively.

And if there is no momentum uncertainty, as in the case $|\psi \rangle = |p \rangle$, then $\sigma _p =0$, so you'd think that the product is also 0. However, for a momentum eigenstate, the position wave function is proportional to $e^{ipx}$. If you try to calculate $\sigma_x$, you will get infinity. So you have

$$\sigma_x \sigma _p = \infty * 0 \geq  \hbar/2 ?$$

This is an indefinite form and a priori can equal any number. However you can prove that the inequality still holds (maybe lacking a bit of mathematical rigor): $\psi (p)$ will be a delta function $\delta (p'-p)$, and you can write this as a limit of gaussian functions. For any of the gaussians in the limit the uncertainty principle holds.

Lastly: Since (according to your edit) you're looking for an answer with high school math background, I'll just summarize without any technical stuff.

> Summary (no math background needed)

Mathematically, in quantum mechanics you can conceive of a particle with definite momentum, i.e. with 100% chance that the momentum takes a particular value $p$. But that on its own does not violate the Heisenberg uncertainty principle: The HUP says that the error in position and momentum cannot *both* be arbitrarily small at the same time. However, having 0 error in *one* of the variables does not mean the HUP is violated, it just means you have to have large (actually infinite) uncertainty in the other variable.

There is a caveat to this. Mathematically you can conceive of a state that has a definite momentum, and this state is very useful in quantum mechanics. But there are reasons to believe that such a state would never exist physically: you could get states which *approximate* this state very well, but you'd never quite get there. So if you like, you can think of the definite momentum state as an *almost* definite momentum state. A state with *almost* definite momentum has almost a 100% chance to give a momentum very close to $p$, and that chance is so close to 100% that you can just consider it exactly 100% for most purposes.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that you can have as precise a measurement as you want with momentum if you aren't also trying to measure the position as well.

Comment: Actually an assumption of the uncertainty relation is that the state is normalizable; states of definite momentum are not so the HUR should be used *with extreme care* in this case, i.e. not valid.

Comment: @user27084 do you mean to say that the statement, say, "definite position" mean that if we did an experiment, we will find the particle in there somewhere?

Comment: But if that were the case, then uncertainties would be non zero right? As we are calculating the uncertainty (standard deviation) after doing a series of experiments?

Comment: "definite position" would not just mean that we will find the particle somewhere, it is even more information than that: If a state has definite position $x=2$ (in some units), it means there is a 100% chance that it will be found at $x=2$ if we measure its position. That leaves no uncertainty.